# DI: Register-Resolve-Release when using child containers

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

There's this software, X, which has this really complicated API that I have to write a facade for. I wrote a class library, `XClientLibrary`, and I made it using DI and IoC container (Unity). This was possible because my library exports services (interfaces) so users are not aware of the concrete classes which use constructor DI. They're also unaware of the IoC container.

The "root service" is a `IXClient` instance which is supposed to be created once and used as long as the application runs. (It is a desktop application btw). The X-client allows users to connect to X-hosts if they know the URL. A X-host allows users to access host's services and their services and so on (quite a complex object graph). This is sample user code:

```
// 1. app startup
XClientProvider provider = new XClientProvider(); // call only once per app
IXClient xClient = provider.GetClient(); // always returns the same instance    
xClient.Startup();

// 2. app normal usage
IXHost host = xClient.ConnectToHost(new Uri("http://localhost")); // return new instance each time
IXService1 service = host.GetThis();
IXService2 otherService = service.DoThat();
...
host.Dispose();

// get another host, consume it, dispose it, etc
...

// 3. app shutdown    
xClient.Shutdown();
provider.Dispose();
```

I tried to follow Mark Seemann's suggestions to implement this, but I'm not sure if they apply to a class library too. The client provider is the composition root, which is the only place where the IoC container is used. The composition root follows the [RRR pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx):

- the container is created on `new XClientProvider()` and configured
- the container resolves `IXClient` when calling `GetClient()`
- the container is disposed on `provider.Dispose()`

Things get complicated when the container is asked to resolve `IXHost`. Its implementation is:

```
internal class XHost : IXHost    
   public XHost(Uri uri, IXService1 service1)
```

The client is supposed to create `XHost` instances, so its implementation needs to know how to create `IXService1`:

```
internal class XClient : IXClient
    public XClient(Func<IXService1> xService1DelegateFactory)
```

Invoking the delegate factory reaches the container which creates a `IXService1`. Also, let's say that in this graph there is a class `XComponent7` which requires the exact `IXService1` instance which was used to create the host:

```
internal class XComponent7 : IXService7
    public XComponent7(Func<IXService1> service1DelegateFactory)
```

I have to use `Func` to deal with the circular dependency. The container should be configured such that once a `IXService1` was resolved, it will provide the same instance whenever asked to resolve `IXService1`.

---

Now it gets really complicated. I want to restrict this behavior "per host resolve", meaning once a host is created the container should create a `IXService1` and cache it and provide it to whatever component needs it, as long as the component is part of the object graph of the host. I also need a way to dispose all components when a host is disposed.

I was thinking I can do it using child containers. I can create one when users call `ConnectToHost`, ask it to resolve the host and dispose it on host disposal. The main container is still alive and won't be disposed until they call `Dispose` on the provider.

Problem is, I think it breaks the RRR pattern. So I wonder how RRR works when child container are involved... Maybe the `IXHost` is another "root" which can be directly resolved by the composition root? Or maybe there's a really smart Unity lifetime manager which can do what I need?

Comment: Before I even try to figure out your object graph and what you want to do with it: Could you please explain what exactly you mean by client, host, service and component? For me the clients seem to offer access to what you call hosts (like a registry of some kind?). These hosts offer services you call to actually do something?

Comment: @Sebastian Services and components are defined [here](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Services-and-Components.ashx). Host is some kind of DNS host and the client is the means to access a host. My users can't do `var host = new Host(uri)` so I had to provide another way for them to do it: `var host = client.ConnectToHost(uri)`. I'm not sure that "client" is a good name though...

Answer (score 1):

@Suiden So my understanding is: Your client is something that lets you lookup hosts (like a  registry). Hosts offer services implemented by components. Every application has exactly one instance of your lookup/client. Your components not only implement services but might need other services to do their job. You want to resolve all parts of that object graph exactly once and when you dispose your client throw all of it away.

A couple of thoughts:

Circular references between dependencies (or services) is something you should try to avoid. If these services need each other that indicates they should be one service. That's what high cohesion, low coupling is about.

Unity does not clean up after itself. That means that even if you dispose a container that will not dispose the objects created by that container. The cleanup feature is on the [wish list for Unity vNext](http://entlib.uservoice.com/forums/89245-general/suggestions/1672391-unity-lifetimes-teardown-should-dispose-objects-c)

If you want to resolve an instance of some service and cache that instance inside your client/host wherever you should have a look at *Lazy*. It takes a *Func* to create an instance of *T* and evaluates that *Func* the first time the value is requested. So you can inject the *Func* into your classes or [teach Unity to inject *Lazy* instances directly](http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2010/05/lazy-and-ienumerable-support-comes-to.html).

Child containers are a feature I find less than usefull. You can scope registration information and object lifetimes. But to make use of these scopes you would have to reference the appropriate child container. That means you are dropping dependency injection in favor of the [ServiceLocator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

Comment: - It's true every app has exactly one instance of my client. This is one graph which I need disposed when the app closes. However the client can create hosts, so these are N other graphs which I need disposed when the app disposes the hosts.  
- I'll think more about the  circular dependency stuff. Thanks for the hint  
- If Unity leaves a mess behind then I'll replace it  
- I started using Lazy at this project, although I can't afford 4.0 so I have my own implementation  
- ServiceLocator... yeah, been there, did it. Then I saw Mark's post couple of months ago so now I try to avoid it

Comment: @Suiden if my answer was helpful it would be great if you could mark it as such.